# Android Firebase chat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm planning to develop an Android `firebase` chat.
I'm new to Android and Firebase.

Here is the table I want to create.

```
Customers
    -Firebase push ID
        -cu_id:""
        -cu_name:""
        -cu_status:""
        -cu_ae_id:""

AccountExecutive
    -Firebase push ID
        -ae_id:""
        -ae_name:""
        -ae_status
```

Is this table is possible in Firebase?
And how can I connect this two table into "chats" table?
Any table structure you can suggest to me?

The idea is, the Account Executive can send chat message to Customers.

Then the Customer can send chat message to Account Executive assign to him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0

This document describes how firebase works step by step working.